# How to use NSExpression for linePattern to increase distance between images

Tags: swift, mapbox

I'm trying to show route direction on the map using image
This is my code

```
let image = UIImage(named: "arrow.right")!
style.setImage(image, forName: "arrow")
let dashedLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline-dash", source: routeSource)
dashedLayer.lineWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 4)
dashedLayer.linePattern = NSExpression(?????) // <------- what should i use here
```

If i'll use `NSExpression(forConstantValue: "arrow")`, image will draw with minimum spacing.

I think i should use

```
NSExpression(forMGLStepping: , from: , stops: )
```

But what to paste, i can't find out.

If simple example:

Now it's drawing (>>>>>>>>>)

I need (>--->--->--->)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out right solution

```
let imageLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "direction", source: source)
imageLayer.symbolSpacing = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 50)
imageLayer.iconColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.white)
imageLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "arrow")
imageLayer.symbolPlacement = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "line")
imageLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
```